# Select first Row if configuration exists, otherwise select NULL Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Given an instance of SQL Server 2008, imagine there's a table named `@Configuration`, which has three columns: `ID`, `Code`, and `SubCode`. There should be no duplicate rows for `Code` and `SubCode`.

Now imagine another detail level table `@ConfigurationDetails` which have duplicate rows of `Code` and Sub code may be available of `SubCode` as Null.

If `SubCode` is available then pick `Amt` and `Data` direct from the detail table and if `SubCode` is not available in the details table then pick `Amt` and `Data` in `NULL` record

(NOTE: `SubCode=NULL` entry is always available for every Configuration row  )

Any ideas on where to start?

e.g.
a simple example...
table

```
declare @Configuration TABLE ( 
      ID INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
      Code VARCHAR(50),
      SubCode VARCHAR(50)


);

declare @ConfigurationDetails TABLE 
( 
    Code VARCHAR(50),
    SubCode VARCHAR(50),
    Amt MONEY,
    Data VARCHAR(123)
);


INSERT INTO @Configuration VALUES
('BR1','Sub1'),
('BR1','Sub2'),
('BR1','Sub3'),
('BR1','Sub4'),
('BR2','Sub1'),
('BR2','Sub2')

INSERT INTO @ConfigurationDetails VALUES
('BR1','Sub1',500,'BR1 Sub1 Data'),
('BR1','Sub2',600,'BR1 Sub2 Data'),
('BR1',NULL,700,'BR1 Data'),
('BR2','Sub1',500,'BR2 Sub1 Data'),
('BR2',NULL,700,'BR2 Data')


INPUT:
@SubCode  = 'Sub1', @Code = 'BR1'

OUTPUT:
Code    SubCode Amt Data
====    ======= === ====
BR1     Sub1    500 BR1 Sub1 Data

INPUT:
@SubCode  = 'Sub4', @Code = 'BR1'

OUTPUT:
Code    SubCode Amt Data
====    ======= === ====
BR1     NULL    700 BR1 Data
```

Comment: Firstly your example has errors , you cannot insert value to identity column (unless use Insert_identity on ), so handle your example then revisit again.

Comment: This sounds very much like a school assignment. Have you tried to solve this yourself? If so, where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like

```
SELECT *
FROM   @Configuration c
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM   @ConfigurationDetails cd
                    WHERE  c.Code = cd.Code
                           AND ( c.SubCode = cd.SubCode
                                  OR c.SubCode IS NULL )
                    ORDER  BY cd.SubCode DESC --Order the not null match first if it exists
                   ) CA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte
AS (
        SELECT  a.ID, 
                a.Code, 
                a.SubCode, 
                b.SubCode as bSubCode, 
                b.Amt, 
                b.Data,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.CODE, a.SubCode ORDER BY B.SUBCODE desc) as RN
          FROM  @Configuration as a
          LEFT  JOIN @ConfigurationDetails as b ON b.Code = a.Code
                AND (a.SubCode = b.SubCode OR b.SubCode IS NULL)
        )
        SELECT * FROM cte
        where rn=1
```